# Making sure string doesn't contain http(s) nor doesn't start with a forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to append a root url to a redirect url, but ONLY if it doesn't contain `http` or `https` **AND** doesn't *start with* a `/`.

I have this code which *appears* to work:

```
$redirect_url = '/foo';

if (!preg_match('#https?://|^/#', $redirect_url)) {
    $redirect_url = 'http://' . $redirect_url;
}
```

But I'm wondering instead of using the `|` character for `OR` shouldn't I be using `AND` - but I'm not sure how in regex?

Comment: if you don't want to allow the both then `OR` would does the job.

Comment: ! (x OR y) is what you want. It can't both start with http(s) and / at the same time anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `|` using this regex:

```
^(https?:/)?/
```

In code:

```
if (!preg_match('#^(https?:/)?/#', $redirect_url)) {
    $redirect_url = 'http://' . $redirect_url;
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/1)

Comment: nvm.. I think I understand it :)

Comment: Yes sure. It matches line start using `^` and then `http:/` or `https:/` since we have optional `s` using `s?`. Also keep in mind `?` after `(https?:/)?` make whole thing optional. Finally it matches next `/` that makes it match: `http://` OR `https://` OR `/` at line start. For more explanation you can also check description in my demo link.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems I understood it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your regex to,

```
if (!preg_match('#^(?:https?://|/)#', $redirect_url)) {
    $redirect_url = 'http://' . $redirect_url;
}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/2)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your need, but is that what you want?

```
if (preg_match('#(?!.*https?://)(?!^/)#', $redirect_url)) {
    $redirect_url = 'http://' . $redirect_url;
}
```